How to decrease the direct attribution for iOS app?
We are implementing the app version for our website using react native for iOS which we are loading in a WebView component in the iOS app. We see a spike in direct attribution of traffic.
Can someone help us how this direct attribution of app can be reduced.
What are things that we can try and eliminate it from the app?
Expecting a reduce in number of direct attribution in GA4.
